# Alternative to Android Action Bar using buttons or radio group

Tags: android

I would like to create an simple menu type Action Bar along the top.  I like using buttons, but need the color or image to change and hold when on selected link.  Or else, could a radio button be used as an alternative to Action Bar?  I would like it to look like the menu tabs on this screenshot link:  [view link here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-oWNA6kVaMEY/TkuaZXH-H-I/AAAAAAAAAJE/5GAf3VE_TFw/s1600/diet_assistant2.png)Thank you!

Comment: Go to Google and search for beginner tutorials.

Comment: "need the color or image to change and hold when on selected link" -- that sounds like rather odd behavior. You might consider making some images depicting the behavior you want, or, better yet, point to existing apps that behave this way. "could a radio button be used as an alternative to Action Bar?" -- I don't see how. I mean, you can use a stone as an alternative to an ice cube, but that's not the normal role of a stone.

Comment: I would just use the new Action Bar supporting Android 3.0+, but since over half Android Users are below that, I want the app to work on all devices.